# Android: How do I programmatically set my camera's "GPS tag" flag?

Tags: android, android-camera

Programming on Android API 8. Assume that the device GPS signal is enabled and has a location fix:

The camera app that comes with my Samsung Galaxy tab has a setting that allows photos to be geo tagged. In the camera app if I got to "Settings | (scroll to the bottom) GPS tag" I can turn this feature on and off.

I want to turn this setting on/off programmatically - is this possible? If so, can you share some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Camera.Parameter methods

- setGpsLongitude (double longitude)
- setGpsLatitude (double latitude)
- setGpsAltitude (double altitude)
- setGpsTimestamp (long timestamp)
- setGpsProcessingMethod (String processing_method)

before taking the picture using Camera#takePicture.
You'll have to get the latitude and longitute yourself programmatically.
Also, you'll need to first call Camera.Parameter#removeGpsData()

Comment: That is not what I was asking. I know how to view/edit Exif tag values - I want know if I can view the camera setting for turning on "GPS tag" & if I can view it can I then edit it?

Comment: do you got any solution for your question? If yes, Please Provide your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. I could not find the link that explains why as reference, but it has to do with the way apps work. There are some things you cannot do when calling another app into your app.

You will have to create a custom camera app and use Camera.Parameter methods as described by beerockxs.